# Why doesn't the US suppress the use of Spanish, similar to how France enforces its official language?

Tags: united-states, languages

Looking at the [Spanish language distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language_in_the_United_States) in the US one can see that English is slowly losing its dominant status in the southern parts:

[image: spanish in usa]

So why don't American politicians attempt to restrict the use of Spanish and promote English instead? Are there any government plans to attempt to reverse the [hispanicization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanicization) of the US? For an example of language enforcement in France, see [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toubon_Law) about the Toubon Law.

Comment: This map does not show that English is losing its dominance.  You need at least two points in time to show a change over time.  Compare it to a map from 1835 and I think you'll find that it shows an increase in the prominence of English.  (Hint: most of the brown areas were Mexico in 1835).

Comment: @phoog there were [11 million Spanish speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language_in_the_United_States#Geographic_distribution) in 1980 and now there are 41 million. Most of the increase happened in the southern states, so it seems like Spanish is clearly heading towards complete domination in certain areas.

Comment: So what?  The question seems to presuppose a national interest in the suppression of Spanish.  Why should the US *want* to suppress it?

Comment: @phoog because once a part of your country starts speaking a different language, it is likely to want to become independent or join a neighboring state. See: Quebec, Catalonia, Crimea. There are already issues with Puerto Rico attempting to gain independence, mostly because having a different language gives them a separate identity.

Comment: None of those three places is at all analogous to the US southwest.  Quebec was well established as a linguistically and culturally French territory before being taken over by the British.  Catalonia similarly had its own identity for hundreds of years before being joined with Castile in a dynastic marriage in the 15th century.  Crimea's history has far more to do with its strategic military importance than with the desires of its population.  Besides, if the US wants to discourage secessionist sentiment then suppressing the culture is *precisely the wrong thing to do.*

Comment: @phoog well, New Mexico used to be a part of Mexico, so they also have plenty of historical connections to the Spanish culture. If that's not true and Spanish speakers in the US don't want any special concessions and fully support the integrity of the country - feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: The body of the question doesn't provide any info about France. BTW, which languages is it fighting against? Regional dialects, or Arabic?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toubon_Law. They're fighting English and some regional dialects.

Comment: @JonathanReez - PR is a poor example - they were always independent(ish) and not a state; and there's also a strong pro-joining sentiment there as well.

Comment: What does the map show? People who are able to speak Spanish, or people who only know Spanish? **It is the latter number the one that you should be concerned with**

Comment: @SJuan76 most people in Catalonia do speak Spanish, but Spain is still worried about them leaving.

Comment: That is an unrelated issue. The idea that different language equals to support for independence is naive at best (look at Switzerland), and certainly it makes it seem as if you are asking two different questions (1 - Trends in Spanish use?, 2 - Use of Spanish == political risk?).

Comment: @SJuan76 I'll ask as a separate question about 2.

Comment: @SJuan76 the census asked "does this person speak a language other than English at home" and, if so, "What is this language" and "How well does this person speak English."  The map presumably reports people who answered "yes" and "Spanish," and it obviously doesn't represent the responses to the last question.  See https://www.census.gov/prod/2013pubs/acs-22.pdf.

Comment: Also, the map makes it look like a huge proportion of US Spanish speakers live in New Mexico, but that's because NM has a relatively large counties that are sparsely populated, so a few thousand Spanish speakers in these counties cause much of NM to be dark brown.  Look at the [population density map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Mexico#/media/File:New_Mexico_population_map.png).  The vast majority of the state has fewer than 10 people per square mile (3.9 per km^2).  NM has around 700K Spanish speakers while the NYC metropolitan area has 3.5 million.

Answer (score 7):

The U.S. has no formally recognized official language. There have been attempts to declare English the official language, but none have been successful. There have been successful attempts in the U.S. to limit other languages from gaining prominence or reduce their use. German was extremely common in the original colonies, but English advocates were successful in defeating votes to print official documents in German in addition to English.

France in contrast has French as an official language, and is also very active in promoting and defending the use of French as a language. France also has an official body dedicated to regulating French as a language which helps with the perception of them more actively promoting French than the U.S. promotes English.

While the U.S. may not do much in the way of official support of English there is a huge amount of soft pressure created by trade dominance, tourism, the internet, etc. The current political climate also limits to a small degree what the U.S. could do to support English without being labeled xenophobic, Racist, Imperial, or otherwise criticized.

Comment: But isn't the US afraid of losing it's southern properties once enough people become "Spaniards" rather than "Americans"?

Comment: @JonathanReez - they are states, not "properties". And absent Mexico starting and **winning** a war to conquer them (or said states starting and winning a civil war to secede - last time [it was tried it didn't turn out well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Civil_War)), it can't "lose" them.

Comment: @JonathanReez the Spanish-speaking people in the US are in vast proportion no more Spaniards than are the English-speaking population Englishmen and -women.  There's a far more important issue in the question of secession: economic well being.  Catalonia and Quebec probably have less to lose by leaving Spain and Canada than would New Mexico by leaving the US.

Comment: Just to say, we french people do have the "Academie Francaise" but we usually ... how do you say this ... fart in their general direction.
They are arbiters of what's "proper" French, but baguette to that.